# problema al insertar con sql

Tags: mysql, sql

intento agregar esto a mi base de datos pero me lanza un error, se que lo que me dice es que no reconoce la columna hipnosBlood(este es el dato que tiene que almacenar en la columna usuario), pero no entiendo porque reconoce el dato como columna

```
"INSERT INTO users (usuario, nombre, apellido, rol, password, sexo) VALUES ("+data.usuario+","+data.nombre+","+data.apellido+","+data.rol+","+data.password+","+data.sexo+")"
```

error:

> 'Unknown column \'hipnosBlood\' in \'field list\''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la query SQL cuando envíes cadenas ponelas entre comillas simples, te doy un ejemplo de como tendrías que enviarle una query de insert, suponiendo que todos los campos son cadenas:

```
INSERT INTO users (usuario, nombre, apellido, rol, password, sexo) 
 VALUES ('hipnosBlood','Pepe', 'Gonzalez','ADMIN','1234','M')
```

Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Joann Buen dia.  'Unknown column \'hipnosBlood\' in \'field list\' te indica que no existe esa columna, quizas debas considerar cambiar el nombre de ese campo o el nombre de la columna en la tabla.

"INSERT INTO users (usuario, nombre, apellido, rol, password, sexo) VALUES ("+data.usuario+","+data.nombre+","+data.apellido+","+data.rol+","+data.password+","+data.sexo+")"

POR

"INSERT INTO users (hipnosBlood, nombre, apellido, rol, password, sexo) VALUES ("+data.hipnosBlood+","+data.nombre+","+data.apellido+","+data.rol+","+data.password+","+data.sexo+")"

Saludos